# How to add items in anonymous type and retrieve list of item

Tags: vb.net

I have a `DataTable` in the variable `dtLatencyValues`.

I select data from this `DataTable` into a list of an anonymous type:

```
Dim _Latency = dtLatencyValues.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(Function(x) x("Customer_Name") = str1(0).CustName AndAlso x("Site_Name") = str1(j).sitname)
                   .Select(Function(x) New With 
                   {
                        .CommLat = x("Committed_Value"), 
                        .ActLat = x("ActualLatencyVal"), 
                        .ToContry = x("Site_To_Name")
                   })
                   .OrderBy(Function(a) a.ToContry)
                   .DefaultIfEmpty().ToList()
```

I want to add :

```
Dim temp = New With {.CommLat = "-", .ActLat = "-", .ToContry = str1(j).sitname}
```

into my `_Latency` list and then retrieve data from the final `_Latency` list.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`Insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim _Latency = dtLatencyValues.AsEnumerable()...ToList()
Dim temp = New With {.CommLat = "-", .ActLat = "-", .ToContry = str1(j).sitname}

_Latency.Insert(0, temp) ' insert as first element '
' or '
_Latency.Add(temp) ' insert as last element '
```

Comment: _Latency.Insert(0, temp)    it giving error "value of type anonymous type cannot be converted in to anonymous type "

Comment: @osama_1200 Then double check that you use the same anonymous types in your query and in when creating `tmp`. Check that the properties are the same (same name, same type etc.)

Comment: i solve it  in such that:                                                                                        Dim tlist As New List(Of Object)                                                         tlist.Add(temp)                                                                              tlist.Add(_Latency)                                                                                        But the problem is that how can i retrieve the values of        "tlist"

Comment: @osama_1200 That's the wrong way to "solve" the problem. Just make sure the types are the same, then reading the values is no problem at all. Is `x("Committed_Value")` a string? is `x("ActualLatencyVal")` a string? Is `x("Site_To_Name")` the same type as `str1(j).sitname`?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to set `Option Strict On` to help avoid some issues like this.  Your problem is that the properties of the anonymous type created by the LINQ query are all typed as `Object`, since `DataRow.Item` (the `x("field name")` in your code) returns `Object`.  When you want to add an item, the anonymous types need to match, and `AnonymousType(Of Object, Object, Object)` doesn't match `AnonymousType(Of String, String, String)`.

If you change your query to use the correct types, you should be able to add new items more easily, e.g. (not sure if these are the correct types for your data!):

```
Dim _Latency = dtLatencyValues.AsEnumerable() _
    .Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Customer_Name") = str1(0).CustName AndAlso x.Field(Of String)("Site_Name") = str1(j).sitname) _
    .Select(Function(x) New With 
        {
            .CommLat = x.Field(Of String)("Committed_Value"), 
            .ActLat = x.Field(Of String)("ActualLatencyVal"), 
            .ToContry = x.Field(Of String)("Site_To_Name")
        }) _
    .OrderBy(Function(a) a.ToContry) _
    .DefaultIfEmpty().ToList()
_Latency.Add(New With {.CommLat = "-", .ActLat = "-", .ToContry = str1(j).sitname})
```

You may need to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` for the `.Field(Of String)` calls to work.

**EDIT**

Here's a complete working example - VS2013 console project.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim dtLatencyValues = New DataTable()
        dtLatencyValues.Columns.Add("Customer_Name", GetType(String))
        dtLatencyValues.Columns.Add("Site_Name", GetType(String))
        dtLatencyValues.Columns.Add("Committed_Value", GetType(String))
        dtLatencyValues.Columns.Add("ActualLatencyVal", GetType(String))
        dtLatencyValues.Columns.Add("Site_To_Name", GetType(String))

        dtLatencyValues.Rows.Add("CustA", "SiteA", "Com1", "Act1", "STN1")
        dtLatencyValues.Rows.Add("CustA", "SiteA", "Com2", "Act2", "STN2")
        dtLatencyValues.Rows.Add("CustA", "SiteB", "Com1", "Act1", "STN1")
        dtLatencyValues.Rows.Add("CustB", "SiteB", "Com1", "Act1", "STN1")

        Dim custName = "CustA"
        Dim siteName = "SiteA"

        Dim _Latency = dtLatencyValues.AsEnumerable() _
            .Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Customer_Name") = custName AndAlso x.Field(Of String)("Site_Name") = siteName) _
            .Select(Function(x) New With
            {
                .CommLat = x.Field(Of String)("Committed_Value"),
                .ActLat = x.Field(Of String)("ActualLatencyVal"),
                .ToContry = x.Field(Of String)("Site_To_Name")
            }) _
            .OrderBy(Function(a) a.ToContry) _
            .DefaultIfEmpty().ToList()
        _Latency.Add(New With {.CommLat = "-", .ActLat = "-", .ToContry = siteName})

    End Sub

End Module
```

Setting a breakpoint at the `End Sub` line and inspecting `_Latency` shows:

[image: Watch window]

Comment: _Latency.Add(New With {.CommLat = "-", .ActLat = "-", .ToContry = str1(j).sitname})                                                                                                          it giving error "Value of type <anonymous type>" can not be converted to <anonymous type>

Comment: @osama_1200 Without knowing what your `DataTable` and your actual code looks like, it's hard to know what is going on.  I'll add a complete working example that may help you debug.